# Excel VBA change cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I need help. It looks so easy, but it doesn't work...
for some reason it shows an error if I want to change the color of the cell, inside an IF construction , which will be equal to "Error" based on the comparison result.
Error in "Res(i, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 6" line
Code:

```
    Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet, ResSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Src(), Res()

     For i = 1 To UBound(Res)
        If Res(i, 4) < Now Then
            Res(i, 14) = "Error"
            Res(i, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        ElseIf Res(i, 5) < Res(i, 4) Then
            Res(i, 14) = "Error"
            Res(i, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
            Res(i, 14) = "OK"
        End If
   Next i
```

Comment: What exactly is `Res`? I think you're confusing arrays and ranges.

Comment: Could you post the complete code? There may be something wrong with the part preceding this code snippet. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66232689/edit) your post at any time.